# White stripe before beamercolorbox

Tags: beamer

I'm to make custom frame title at beamer. All settings work good, but I cannot remove white stripe before color box.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{   \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
        {\bfseries\Large\strut\hspace{10pt}\insertframetitle\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}\insertframenumber\hspace{10pt}\strut}
    \vskip+0.65ex%    
        \setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=red}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0pt
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Frame title]

Comment: Please post a compileable MWE, starting with `\documentclass`

Comment: Posting incomplete code is really not so good.

Comment: Added MWE. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the way to fix it. Just added `\nointerlineskip` before `\begin{beamercolorbox}`.

Comment: WTG solving your own problem!